# Why might Visual Studio be unable to authenticate to an Azure artifact package source?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

My company's NuGet feed is inaccessible via the package manager interface in Visual Studio 2022.

My company has a NuGet source with an URL like https://elcia.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/MYCOMPANY/nuget/v3/index.json. Authentication is linked to our active directory and should all just work, and has worked in the past. I can access the URL in my browser, and I can access the feed via the package manager console inside Visual Studio. `nuget list -Source MYCOMPANY` works just fine. But the package manager interface can't access the feed, and leaves a 401 unauthorized error in the output.

Restarting VS, restarting my machine, deleting my credentials in the credential manager have no impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's somehow linked to updating my Visual Studio licence. When I choose `Help => Register => Check for an updated licence` it all works.